# Add semicolon while appending text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which appends two different text from different column into a single cell. What I want to do is: To add a semicolon separating the two different text.

This is the line that does the appending:

```
If Not Sheets("DRG").Range("E" & MatchRow + 1).Value = vbNullString Then .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value & IIf(Not .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = vbNullString, ";", "") & Sheets("DRG").Range("Q" & MatchRow + 1).Value & Sheets("DRG").Range("S" & MatchRow + 1).Value
```

Col Q and COl S are two column and I need to add a semicolon between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
If Not Sheets("DRG").Range("E" & MatchRow + 1).Value = vbNullString Then _
    .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value & _
    IIf(Not .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = vbNullString, ";", "") & _
    Sheets("DRG").Range("Q" & MatchRow + 1).Value & ";" & Sheets("DRG").Range("S" & MatchRow + 1).Value
```

Comment: Sure. Waiting for 10 mins to pass..as SO allows to mark an answer only after 10 mins

Comment: @stackmark didn't know that, from answer ? or from opening the post ?

Answer (score 2):

```
If Not Sheets("DRG").Range("E" & MatchRow + 1).Value = vbNullString Then .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value & IIf(Not .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = vbNullString, ";", "") & Sheets("DRG").Range("Q" & MatchRow + 1).Value & ";" & Sheets("DRG").Range("S" & MatchRow + 1).Value
```

Comment: seriously ? again by seconds :)  it took me a while just to understand his very long code line (which I have a feeling I know where it's coming from)

Comment: @ShaiRado, seems like seconds are not going to matter...(and your feeling is quite right)

Comment: congrats on the 20K !

Answer (score 1):

```
If Not Sheets("DRG").Range("E" & MatchRow + 1).Value = vbNullString Then    .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value & IIf(Not .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = vbNullString, ";", "") & ";" & Sheets("DRG").Range("Q" & MatchRow + 1).Value & ";" &Sheets("DRG").Range("S" & MatchRow + 1).Value
```

Try this edit.